# VirtualBox: Can't add any mass storages or delete them

Tags: virtualbox, debian, vdi

So there is the following issue.
I had the problem, that I've tried to add some mass storages to my VM.
Then I've deleted them and now I just see in the logs, that the entry still persists (see screenshot)

[image: Screenshot of my virtual drives]

Now when I try to add another drive, it's not possible anymore because it's grayed out.

[image: Virtual Drives]

I've tried to find a log file or a `.cfg` file to delete the entries, but I can't find them.

Do you have any tips how to solve this problem?

Comment: Use the Virtual Storage Manager to manage your VDI files. It will automatically delete them from VM's too. Also, keep in mind, that in order to change a VM, the VM itself must be shutdown, not paused nor saved or running. Only then, the VM itself can be edited.

Comment: I've tried that out, but it doesn't worked.
Everything is shutted down, but just I mentioned, I can't get these storages out of my list, even if they don't exists anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I find it out by myself.

I went to the following folder: C:\Users\MyUser.VirtualBox
There was a file called "VirtualBox.xml" and "VirtualBox.xml-prev"

[image: VirtualBox.xml File]

I've deleted these entries (just the entries with the VDIs) and then the entries were gone and I was able again to add VDIs.

Just as I mentioned, the VDIs were already deleted, but because of the entries, I wasn't able to add another one.

With this, I've solved it. But be carefully editing this file. Always keep a backup of this one.